# How reliable is TelephonyManager.getSimOperator() on CDMA devices?

Tags: android, cdma

This post indicates that this function is bogus:
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg69276.html
But I tried it on 2 CDMA devices (Android 2.2 and 2.3) and both returned the correct MCC and MNC. Was there a bug in the earlier versions of Android in the function for CDMA? Can I trust the results from this call for CDMA devices running Android 2.2 or later?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IS telephony manager values changeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551078/is-telephony-manager-values-changeable)